# C++ application crash detect on windows

Tags: c++, windows

One of my C++ MFC application randomly crash on some windows(7,xp) computers. This applications use some third party libraries (Apache axis) and when i check with dependency walker it shows application exit after loading a DLL related to this third party libraries.

So I need a way to detect what is the crash cause for this application. Is there any way to do this?

- I read it can use `.pdb` files to host together with `.exe` file identify the crash issue, but as usual Microsoft doesn't have clear documentation how to use.
- I try to use `IBM purify` trial version. but I doesn't show any valid information.
- I tried to use `WinDbg`. but i couldn't find how to use it.

Any assist really appreciate.

EDIT: crash report added

```
Problem Event Name:                        APPCRASH
  Application Name:                             installer.exe
  Application Version:                           5.0.1.0
  Application Timestamp:                     51ac0bdc
  Fault Module Name:                          AxisXMLParserXerces.dll
  Fault Module Version:                        1.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:                  51ac0016
  Exception Code:                                  c0000005
  Exception Offset:                                0000161d
  OS Version:                                          6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:                                             18441
  Additional Information 1:                  0a9e
  Additional Information 2:                  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3:                  0a9e
Additional Information 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789`
```

Comment: There is tons of info on pdb files & windbg and other debuggers - you can start here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Are crashed Windows machines 32bit and working ones 64 bit?

Comment: One more link - http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know

Comment: @fatih_k: This is a 32 bit build application. testing in 32 bit computers

Comment: @user93353: Thank you for your links, actually I read your third link before come here. I says `why & what to do` than `how to do`. Now I'm trying your first two links.

Comment: Anyone please tell me why peoples down-voted this question?

Comment: People have downvoted it because the question is very broad and doesn't show research effort. A better way would be try using pdbs, windbg etcand say what the exact issues you are facing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are a few steps that you can take to try and locate the source of the problem.

1. Build a release version of the application. Make sure generating PDB files is enabled.
2. Send to client. Make sure they change their "Checking For Solutions" settings (see below).
3. When it crashes they should select "Show Program Details"
4. Have them record the "Fault Module Name", "Fault Executon Code" and "Fault Execution offset"
5. Start the **exact** same version you sent them. The executable and PDB files should be in the directory they were originally saved to when they were built.  (e.g. solution\project\Release). I recommend that before you send them the files you zip them up the entire "Release" directory and stash it somewhere. This way you have an exact copy in case you *accidently* do a clean or other operation that changes the files.
6. In Visual Studio attach to the process with the debugger. (In the "Debug" menu)
7. Break the execution of the application. (Again, in the "Debug" menu)
8. Open the disassembly window. (Once again, in the "Debug" menu)
9. In the "Address" input line at the top of the disassembly window enter the address of the crash based on the *current* load address of the module and the "Execution offset" provided by the crash report. If the module is **not** loaded you will need to modify your application to force load it at startup (this will require you to send them a new version and start over from step 1). Make sure you check for errors as the crash may be a result of a failed DLL load.

From here you will have to wing it based on your knowledge and experience with your application and the third party libraries. At the location where the crash is expected to occur place a breakpoint. Anytime the breakpoint is hit look at the call stack to see where the call is originating from. The problem may be in your code *or* the third party libraries (but probably your code).

You should make an effort to reproduce the crash. Have the users record what actions they were performing when the crash happened. Also have them include any logs that the application or libraries generate.

This will increase your chances of locating the problem but as I stated above you will need to rely on your knowledge of your application and the libraries.

I recommend that before you start you add some code to your application to *force* a crash and run through these steps yourself so you are familiar with them. It may take a few tries before you get it right and you may need to adjust the steps slightly and tailor them to your environment and application. Remember to remove the crash code before you send it to the users.

Since this seems to be you first exposure to using the debugger prepare for some frustration. It's normal.

**Some of these steps assume you are using Visual Studio. WinDbg has a different interface but the concepts are the same.*

***These steps also assume Windows 7. Windows XP shows a window containing similar information when the application crashes and does not need to be reconfigured.*

.
.
.

Changing checking for solution settings

1. Open Control Panel
2. Open the Action Center
3. Click ""Change Action Center Settings"
4. Click "Problem Reporting Settings"
5. Select "Each time a problem occurs, ask me before checking for solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your guide. actually last few day I tried to get the crash point using above method. But so far I couldn't success. Here I added the crash report in my question. In your No:6 point after I type the crash address in the text field, it says cannot find the address. So anything wrong with the way I did it?

Answer (score 1):

[CrashRpt](http://crashrpt.sourceforge.net/) is a good open source tool we use for MFC applications. User can see CrashSender window after a crash happened and then he can send a crash report containing minidump file that can be opened in MS Visual Studio. Of course you need to keep your binaries and corresponding .pdb files for particular build to get a correct call stack while running a crash dump in VS.

Some crashes happen in third party software as well. We're able to notify customers about such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider getting a copy of [AQtrace](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/43658/), which is a tool designed to handle this exact circumstance.  You could also consider setting your client up with [an automation tool](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1094/best-free-or-very-cheap-automation-tool-for-windows-gui-testing), e.g. WinTask, to capture the steps they're using to cause the problem in the first place.  This greatly simplifies reproducing and eliminating it.